# Is the rate of Human Evolution Slowing down?

Tags: evolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is human evolution slowing down?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/is-human-evolution-slowing-down)

I know that this question already exists and have read through. [Is human evolution slowing down?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/is-human-evolution-slowing-down) 
Mutations have to happen agreed, but natural selection would only make a certain DNA more common in the gene pool only if the ones who have that certain DNA have survival advantage or advantages in procreating. The point is if there are 10 people in a hypothetical world(Producing only 1 offspring each) and 1 acquires ability to fend of malaria and the others get malaria and fend it off using medical aid. The next generation sees 10 people with no increase the % of the certain gene in the gene pool of those people. (I know medical aid is not everywhere on the planet and I am not disputing the rate of evolution there) Medical aid along with awareness is reducing the mortality rate and hence the rate of evolution should theoretically slow down. (And yes I know it isn't slowing down in the practical world rather according to an article I read its speeding up, but why?)

Comment: Your logic about medicine is sound, but medical intervention is only one factor. Think about the population size and increase in potential mates afforded by communication and travel technology. My hunch is that the global gene pool is probably currently increasing in diversity, which should increase the potential rate of evolution in the face of serious selection pressure (e.g., a multi-generation pandemic). But short of the global collapse of civilization, I'd suspect that medical intervention would still be the main factor in surviving to have breeding opportunities.